# Entity Framework Code 1st - Mapping many-to-many with extra info

Tags: many-to-many, entity-framework-4.1

I've looked through several of the questions here and am not quite connecting all the (mental) dots on this.  I would appreciate some help.

My Models (code first):

```
public class cgArmorial
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "Armorial ID")]
    public Guid ArmorialID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "User ID")]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DeviceUrl { get; set; }
    public string Blazon { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<cgArmorialAward> ArmorialAwards { get; set; }
}

public class cgArmorialAward
{
    public cgArmorial Armorial { get; set; }
    public cgAward Award { get; set; }
    public DateTime AwardedOn { get; set; }
}
public class cgAward
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "Award ID")]
    public Guid AwardID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Group { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string Blazon { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<cgArmorialAward> ArmorialAwards { get; set; }
}
```

Then in my Context class I have (last 2 entries):

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<cgUser> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<cgEvent> Events { get; set; }
    public DbSet<cgEventType> EventTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<cgArmorial> Armorials { get; set; }
    public DbSet<cgAward> Awards { get; set; }
    public DbSet<cgArmorialAward> ArmorialAwards { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<cgUser>()
                    .HasMany<cgEvent>(e => e.EventAutocrats)
                    .WithMany(u => u.EventAutocrats)
                    .Map(m =>
                    {
                        m.ToTable("EventAutocrats");
                        m.MapLeftKey("UserId");
                        m.MapRightKey("EventId");
                    });
        modelBuilder.Entity<cgUser>()
                    .HasMany<cgEvent>(e => e.EventStaff)
                    .WithMany(u => u.EventStaff)
                    .Map(m =>
                    {
                        m.ToTable("EventStaff");
                        m.MapLeftKey("UserId");
                        m.MapRightKey("EventId");
                    });
        modelBuilder.Entity<cgArmorialAward>()
                    .HasRequired(a => a.Armorial)
                    .WithMany(b => b.ArmorialAwards);
        modelBuilder.Entity<cgArmorialAward>()
                    .HasRequired(a => a.Award)
                    .WithMany();    // b => b.ArmorialAwards
    }
}
```

I am getting this error when I try to run:

> System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'cgArmorialAward' has no
>   key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   System.Data.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet �ArmorialAwards�
>   is based on type �cgArmorialAward� that has no keys defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, as the exception says: You don't have a key defined on your entity `cgArmorialAward`. Every entity must have a key. Change it to the following:

```cs
public class cgArmorialAward
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    [ForeignKey("Armorial")]
    public Guid ArmorialID { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    [ForeignKey("Award")]
    public Guid AwardID { get; set; }

    public cgArmorial Armorial { get; set; }
    public cgAward Award { get; set; }
    public DateTime AwardedOn { get; set; }
}
```

The fields in the composite key are foreign keys to the other two tables at the same time, hence the `ForeignKey` attribute. (I'm not sure if conventions would detect this automatically because you have non-standard names ("cgXXX" for the classes and "XXXId" for the foreign key properties). On the other hand the property names `Armorial` and `Award` match the foreign key property names. I'm not sure if EF conventions would consider this. So, perhaps the `ForeignKey` attribute is not necessary but at least it's not wrong.)