# How do I set an attribute on a many-to-many relationship code first-style?

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, many-to-many, entity-relationship

I'm developing a entity relationship data model for my orchestra planning tool. The final result should be an ASP.NET/MVC4 application.

This is part of my E/R-diagram:

[image: Orchestra planning tool E/R diagram]

In the image above I try to visualize that there is a many-to-many relationship between a `Event` and a `Composition`. In my model I also want the possibility to store a Recording of a `Composition` from a arbitrary `Event` (there can be lots of different recorded versions of the very same composition from different events/concertos).

Here is what I've done so far (with the relevant code for my code-first data model):

```
public class Composition
{
    public Composition()
    {
        Instruments = new Collection<Instrument>();
        Events = new Collection<Event>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Durata { get; set; }

    public virtual Composer Composer { get; set; }
    public virtual Composer Genre { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Instrument> Instruments { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
}
```

_

```
public class Event
{    
    public Event()
    {
        Compositions = new Collection<Composition>();
        Members = new Collection<Member>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Member> Members { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Composition> Compositions { get; set; }
    public virtual Calendar Calendar { get; set; }
    public virtual EventType EventType { get; set; }
    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
}
```

My question: Where in my code do I add the relationship attribute "Recording"?

**EDIT**: Do I have to create a link table or are there better alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is called a many to many relationship with attributes. In order to model N to M relationships in a relational database you will always need an intermediate table. To add the attribute with EF, you need another entity to model the relationship and map it properly. In this question it is explained how to do it:

[Entity Framework Code 1st - Mapping many-to-many with extra info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7448229/entity-framework-code-1st-mapping-many-to-many-with-extra-info)

Comment: Thx for the link. I should do some tests before I mark this as the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer tick, I'm glad you fixed it.